# How to get a locale stored in AsyncStorage with i18next?

Tags: react-native, i18next, asyncstorage, react-i18next

I have a working i18next setup for a react-native app. The only thing I miss, is to retrieve the locale saved by the user in AsyncStorage.

i18next gives you the opportunity to set the locale before the app starts thanks to `18n.use(()=> "locale")`. It works fine as long as the function is not asynchronous.

The thing is that AsyncStorage is asynchronous and requires the `await` keyword. If I do that, the app crashes. So far, my only option is not to allow the user to change his locale and always use his device's.

Is there a way to fix it? Here is my code (with the problematic async/await in `detectLocale()`).

```js
const detectLocale =  async () => {
  const storedLocale = await AsyncStorage.getItem("my-locale");
  if (storedLocale) {
    return JSON.parse(storedLocale);
  }
  const mobileLocale =
    Platform.OS === "ios"
      ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
        NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]
      : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;
  if (mobileLocale) {
    return mobileLocale.split("_")[0];
  }
  return languages.EN;
};

const languageDetector = {
  type: "languageDetector" as LanguageDetectorAsyncModule["type"],
  async: false,
  detect: detectLocale,
  init: () => {},
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

export default i18n
  .use(languageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: languages.EN,
    keySeparator: ".",
    whitelist: [languages.EN, languages.FR],
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
  });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
const detectLocale =  async (callback) => {
  const storedLocale = await AsyncStorage.getItem("my-locale");
  if (storedLocale) {
    return callback(JSON.parse(storedLocale));
  }
  const mobileLocale =
    Platform.OS === "ios"
      ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
        NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]
      : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;
  if (mobileLocale) {
    return callback(mobileLocale.split("_")[0]);
  }
  return callback(languages.EN);
};

const languageDetector = {
  type: "languageDetector" as LanguageDetectorAsyncModule["type"],
  async: true,
  detect: detectLocale,
  init: () => {},
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

export default i18n
  .use(languageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: languages.EN,
    keySeparator: ".",
    whitelist: [languages.EN, languages.FR],
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
  });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected. RN doesn't crash anymore if I wrap my <App/> with `Suspense`, but the loading state never disappear. I have to force a change in the code after the compilation to finally display the app.